# Energy required to levitate an object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, levitation

How much energy is required to maintain a $m$ kilogram body $h$ meters above sea level for a period of $ t$ seconds?

Comment: 0 if you attached a (big enough) helium balloon to it.

Answer (score -1):

Since this question is homework-like, I will only give you a hint and not a full answer – I think you will be able to work out the rest yourself.

In order for an object to levitate one must apply a force $F=ma$ that cancels out the gravitational attraction $F_g=mg$ (where $g$ is the gravitational attraction/acceleration of the earth, around $9.81\,\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}^2$. Since the mass of the object is the same for both equations, $a=-g$. This force $F$ must be applied for $t$ seconds.

The height of the object is actually not relevant if we consider the earth's gravitational acceleration to be constant – this will fail for very large heights.